# IE has different height/width for div than Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I'm having trouble with `div` height and width in IE.

On my web page, http://www.ricominciodame.it/eventi.php, there are some `div`s with a blackboard style.
In Firefox, they all work fine, but in IE (both 7 and 8) the width is lower and the background is cut.

The following is my CSS:

```
div.evento {
    background : white url("images/sfondo_evento.png") top no-repeat;
    width : 260px;
    height : 207px;
    margin:5px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom : 20px;
    padding-left : 20px;
    padding-right : 20px;
    padding-top : 20px;
    padding-bottom : 20px;
    color : white;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your page is running in ie [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) caused by the `DOCTYPE`. You have to use any of these http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Also, it's good to validate always your web site, from [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: This solved my problem. More disturbingly, my HTML 5 declaration resulted in the problem as described in the original question. I guess the world isn't ready for html 5?

Answer (score 6):

Is your doctype set to put the browser in standards mode? For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Sounds like this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I always 'reset' css before designing a new page.
I load my CSS files(notice that I first load the reset, after that the actual layout):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css-styles/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css-styles/all.css" />
```

My reset CSS looks like this:

```
/* CSS Document */

/* Clear all styles */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;}

body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;}

caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";}
/*Ceal all styles END */
```

Comment: That css code is only a fragment of all the code, before that fragment there a little reset rule like this:

html, body, * {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}

Comment: That resolved my issue between browsers..  Chrome and Firefox had the same height on tables, where IE was smaller.    I took just the top "Clear all Styles" and removed the vertical-align: baseline, because that messed up my tables.  Now IE, Chrome, and Firefox all have the same height.   After a little reading, it's because browsers have their own default styles if a style isn't represented.   This was a great find, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

might be a box-model problem: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

I would do something like this:

```
div.evento {
    background : white url("images/sfondo_evento.png") top no-repeat;
    width : 300px;
    height : 207px;
    margin:5px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom : 20px;
    color : white;
}
div.evento-inner {
    padding-left : 20px;
    padding-right : 20px;
    padding-top : 20px;
    padding-bottom : 20px;
}
```

in IE, the padding is taking up 20px on each sides of the 260px width you are declaring.